# Local server (XAMPP) failed to load resource files in codeigniter, it responded with status 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost

I am working with CodeIgniter framework for my company website. In local server, I am getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in browser console, to (what appears) all the links to asset files, css, js, and other various plugins and frameworks. But they work fine online. I cannot seem to find the solution after searching exhaustingly online. Please help!

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/public/plugins/foundation/css/foundation.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/public/plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/public/css/styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/public/css/font-awesome-animation.min.css"/>

<?php
if(isset($css)){
foreach($css as $c){
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $c; ?>"/>
<?php
}
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Relate product-->
<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/public/js/relateproduct.js"></script>
<!--/Relate product-->
<!--slide detail-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/public/plugins/js/unitegallerymin.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/public/plugins/js/ugthemegrid.js'></script>
<!--slide detail-->
```

Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

font-awesome.min.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
styles.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
modal.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: use base_url() to in src and href

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, now I got some good progress! I'm getting most of links back! Cheers